# Four identical classes to receive four different styles via pseudo selector

Tags: css, pseudo-class

Consider this markup - which cannot be changed (I realise adding more classes, or ID's would work, and be easier, but *this markup must be used*).

There will only ever be a maximum of six class "test" elements on the page, so I can write the code "long hand", but I cannot be certain of their surrounding markup/containers.

**How can I style each of these elements with class "test" to display a different colour? I have tried :nth-child and :nth-of-type pseudo selectors without success.**

```
<body>

<div>
 <span class="test">Testing<span>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis</p>
</div>

<span class="test">Testing</span>

<ul>
 <li>Test</li>
 <li class="test">Test</li>
 <li>Test</li>
</ul>

<unknown dynamic container>
 <h2 class="test">Test</h2>
</unknown dynamic container>

</body>
```

Comment: You want this done purely through CSS (which I'm unsure of is possible), or is JavaScript an available option?

Comment: @Martin, I could do it with javaScript, but for the sake of this exercise, I was trying to achieve a purely CSS solution - Or be assured by someone more expert than myself that it is impossible.

Comment: This is why we can specify more than one class on an element, or an absurd idea which is You can define a set of css selectors for each parent `div>.test{color:red;} body>.test{color:pink;}...etc` and base case `*>.test{color:brown;}` at the end

Comment: @Zohir Salak - No, I cannot do that, as I do not know what the surrounding markup will be. I can only see the solution being a pseudo selector counting from "body"

Comment: I can literally only think of Less, SASS or JavaScript solutions. I believe it is not possible through vanilla CSS.

Comment: @Martin, most interested in your SASS solution, plus even more interested how that could even conceivably work given it has to be compiled into CSS anyway? Please tell!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in scss, download a list of colors and generate css [all-the-css-colors](https://css-irl.info/all-the-css-colours/)

```
<li class="test">item 01</li>
<li class="test">item 02</li>
<li class="test">item 03</li>

$colors: red blue green silver black yellow;
@for $colIndex from 1 through length($colors) {
  .test:nth-child(#{length($colors)}n + #{$colIndex}) {
    color: unquote(nth($colors, $colIndex));
  }
}
```

Comment: Kudos for exceeding the questions parameters, but you assert then that compiled CSS as: .test:nth-child(1){color: blue;} .test:nth-child(2){color:red} will answer the question....testing.... no that did not work, I'm sorry